# Swift 3 trying to create and use a UINavigationController programmatically

Tags: swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on an existing application which uses the storyboard but I want to continue development without using the storyboard at all, or nib files.

The existing left menu is a `UITableView` which is not the root controller and does not have a navigation controller associated with it. I have created a `UINavigationController` in the app delegate and want to use this navigation controller to push a new controller. I am able to present a view controller but I want to use push in order to conform with the current UIX.

In the following code nothing happens because `navigationController?` returns nil.

Here is my new code in the app delegate.

```
@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

var navController: UINavigationController?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    navController = UINavigationController()

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    self.window!.rootViewController = navController

    self.window!.backgroundColor = .red

    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let menuViewController = SideMenuViewController()

    menuViewController.navController = navController
```

Then in my side menu controller:

```
import UIKit

class SideMenuViewController: UIViewController {

var navController: UINavigationController?
```

.......

```
   let myViewController = myViewController()

   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`UIViewController` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller):

> `var navigation​Controller:​ UINavigation​Controller?`
>   The nearest
>   ancestor in the view controller hierarchy that is a navigation
>   controller.

Which means when you call `self.navigationController` in a view controller you get the (nearest) navigation controller that `self` is embedded in. Apparently your menu controller is not embedded in the navigation controller hierarchy. Using your app delegate's `navController` member is one way to make this work. Then you can say in your menu view controller:

```
func menuItemFooSelected()
{
    let navController = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).navController
    let myViewController = myViewController()
    navController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Alternatively (and probably preferably), when you set up your initial structure in your app delegate, inject the navigation controller into the side menu controller:

```
class MenuViewController: UIViewController
{
    var navController: UINavigationController?
    ...

    func menuItemFooSelected()
    {
        let myViewController = myViewController()
        self.navController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

In `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`

```
...
let menuViewController = MenuViewController(...)
menuViewController.navController = navController
```

Comment: I had a typo but it did nothing at all. Do the lines let navController... go in the app delegate? I  don't understand what goes in the dotted lines and I will need to use this for many view controllers.

Comment: The dots just stand for how you create your menu view controller because I don't know what initializer you use. The important part is to add the `navController` property to your menu view controller and set this to the navigation controller that you create in your app delegate. You only need to do this once for the menu view controller and then you can push any view controller you like from within that menu view controller.

Comment: I updated the answer to (hopefully) clarify what goes where.

Comment: I updated my question to show what I believe you posted but it still fails with no error.

Comment: I just see that you are not using one of the designated initializers of `UINavigationController`, e.g. `init(root​View​Controller:​)`.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: I don't want to change the existing root view controller and don't want to use the existing storyboard in any way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139031/discussion-between-thm-and-markhorrocks).